# ec2metadata equivalent for Azure virtual machines

Tags: azure, cloud

Is there something similar to `ec2metadata` in Azure virtual machines?

I need to extract data like the the public hostname or the instance id. In Amazon EC2 instances, I can do this:

```
$ ec2metadata --instance-id
i-3a1dcfa3
$ ec2metadata --public-hostname
ec2-54-91-124-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: It has been over a year. How have you solved this in the meantime @ayose?

Answer (score 2):

It seems this question was asked a long time ago, so maybe you already found the answer. If not, though, then have you tried Azure Instance Metadata? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-instancemetadataservice-overview) You can do an http request like this:

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-04-02"
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "compute": {
    "location": "westcentralus",
    "name": "IMDSSample",
    "offer": "UbuntuServer",
    "osType": "Linux",
    "platformFaultDomain": "0",
    "platformUpdateDomain": "0",
    "publisher": "Canonical",
    "sku": "16.04.0-LTS",
    "version": "16.04.201610200",
    "vmId": "5d33a910-a7a0-4443-9f01-6a807801b29b",
    "vmSize": "Standard_A1"
  },
  "network": {
    "interface": [
      {
        "ipv4": {
          "ipAddress": [
            {
              "privateIpAddress": "10.1.0.4",
              "publicIpAddress": "X.X.X.X"
            }
          ],
          "subnet": [
            {
              "address": "10.1.0.0",
              "prefix": "24"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ipv6": {
          "ipAddress": []
        },
        "macAddress": "000D3AF806EC"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Combine with jq, it works very good => curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-04-02" | jq '.compute.name'

Comment: `curl -s -H Metadata:true "169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=curl -s -H Metadata:true "169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2019-06-04" | jq" | jq '.network.interface[0].ipv4.ipAddress[0].publicIpAddress'`